# Campo options limpa após valor selecionado

Tags: html, angular, typescript

Comecei recente com desenvolvimento WEB e tenho estudado ANGULAR para tratar alguns casos no meu trabalho. Tenho cinco opções de select que lista por meio de uma api alguns registros baseados em meu retorno {} , exibidos por minhas interpolações, esses mesmos aparenta normalmente a listagem, porém quando eu uso o evento de click para que seja disparado um evento que chama função da qual consome a api, o mesmo retira os registros da lista deixando somente o item selecionado exibido e sem ter como trocar de elemento dessa lista. Segue o código:

```
<nb-select placeholder="Regional" style="width:19%" ngModel="result">
              <nb-option *ngFor="let i of regional" [value]="i" id="{{i.codigo_regional}}"
                (click)="findPendenciaRegional($event)">
                {{i.nome_regional}}
              </nb-option>
            </nb-select>
```

Função que consome API e pega os dados que são retornados para conseguir popular a lista no HTML:

```
findPendenciaRegional(event) {
    this.pendencia = [];
    this.regional = [];
    this.pendenciaFisicoApiService.pendencias({
      "criterio_de_data": "",
      "data_de": "",
      "data_ate": "",
      "codigo_regional": event.currentTarget.id,
      "codigo_comercial": "",
      "codigo_loja": "",
      "codigo_matriz": "",
      "codigo_funcionario": ""
    })
      .then((s) => {
        this.regional = s.agrupado_regional;
        this.pendencia = s.dados;
      })
      .catch((e) => {
        console.log(e);
      });
  }
```

Comment: Posta o código de findPendenciaRegional()

Comment: Fiz a edição para que exibisse corretamente.

Comment: Confirma pra mim fazendo favor. O seu código gera uma lista que preenche o select, quando você clica neste select ele deve baixar novos dados e preencher o select com novos dados, é isto?

Comment: Também posta ai o JSON de `this.regional` antes de ser modificado e o JSON de `s.agrupado_regional`. Assim ajuda a gente efetuar testes e ajudar a encontrar o problema.

Comment: Ele gera a lista pra preencher o select, quando eu clico ele me busca os registros que é pego pelo ` event.currentTarget.id` 
Eu gostaria que depois que fosse retornado os dados, eu pudesse voltar a selecionar outro nome para realizar outras buscas... Até porquê ainda tenho que implementar um filter nisso pra me retornar baseado numa regra de negócios, somente determinados nomes. Não consigo postar porque é um tamanho extenso.

Comment: Bom, 1º a consulta está substituindo os valores seu select, esta é sua intenção ou é uma falha de codificação? 2º Posta ai pelo menos uns 3~5 itens dos valores que te pedi. Senão fica difícil tentar ajudar por "rumo"/osmose/poder espiritual.

Comment: A intenção é me retornar após clicado, somente os valores da função que consome a API. Mas no select continuar dando opções que posso selecionar outro nome, entende? 

retorno:
``` JSON
  { "agrupamento_regional:
 [ { "codigo_comercial": 244
, "nome_comercial": "BRUNA FERNANDA CARLOTA ALVES" 
}
 ], 

       "dados: [
 {

           "codigo_convenio": 1911,
            "codigo_instituicao": 35,
            "codigo_matriz": 161,
            "codigo_regional": 29,

} 
```

Comment: Não, não entendi direito. Você tem necessidade de inserir novos valores no select de acordo com os dados vindos da API?

Comment: Não. O select é só para retornar conforme regra de negócio.

Eu tenho mais 4 select que são de outras visões. É como e fosse um filtro. Se eu selecionar o Leonardo Getulio que é um regional X, vai me retornar as informações do Leonardo Getulio, regional X com as pendências Y.

Comment: Então tem uma falha no seu código, leia com atenção: no option você dá um loop "for" no array "regional" que está preenchido com os valores que você quer no select. Quando você clica em uma opção, você aciona "findPendenciaRegional()" que altera o valor "this.regional" que é o modelo do select, alterando o select indiretamente removendo seus valores anteriores.

Comment: Você deveria manipular o resultado do "findPendenciaRegional" em outra variável sem ser "regional".

Comment: Era exatamente isso, boa! Só preciso ver como vou fazer pra filtrar agora. Mas obrigado!

Comment: Qual a lógica do seu filtro?

Comment: Em primeiro lugar retornar o ou (os) valores selecionados, já que declarei os campos como multiplos. A API já me retorna "filtrado" se eu passar os codigos devidos.

Comment: Sua mensagem não foi completa a ponto de eu te fornecer uma solução, seria o ideal você dizer algo do tipo: recebo um array com os campos x, y e z, e eu gostaria de filtrar os que o campo y é igual ao valor "valorExemplo". Se você tem filtro via API e é o suficiente para você eu sugiro fortemente utilizar.

Comment: Justo.
Eu tenho os 5 select com os options sendo lista conforme a função do findPendenciaRegional.

Por nivel seria: Regional, Comercial, Matriz, Loja e  Funcionário.

O que quis dizer é que a API me traz os valores se eu passar parametros, por exemplo:

```
{
 "criterio_de_data": "",
 "data_de": "",
 "data_ate": "",
 "codigo_regional":"29",
 "codigo_comercial":"",
 "codigo_loja": "",
 "codigo_matriz":"",
 "codigo_funcionario":""
}
```

Comment: o retorno seria: 

{
    "agrupado_comercial": [
        {
            "codigo_comercial": 244,
            "nome_comercial": "BRUNA FERNANDA CARLOTA ALVES"
        }
    ],

Comment: se eu não passar parametro na chamada da API, retorna todos os codigos de todos meus select (o regional,comercial,funcionario...) Isso é identificado pelo token que determina as visões. Mas tem uma geral que pode ir filtrando, a cada seleção que é chamada pelo código de cada agente, seja comercial, regional etc... Então cada agente tem seu responsavel determinado e por ele é identificado pelo codigo_"agente", isso que não consegui pegar pra por no select e filtrar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quando o método findPendenciaRegional() é chamado, você limpa o Array que é utilizado no ng for.

```
this.regional = [];
```

Comment: Esta observação eu já havia dito à ele em outro post. Talvez faça parte da lógica de negócios dele.

Comment: tem q ver o que ta vindo no this.regional = s.agrupado_regional; então.

Comment: O this.regional quando eu faço o debug só é preenchido quando eu seleciono algum options dentro do select. Ele me retorna um json com:

{ 
"agrupamento_regional: [
             {
             "codigo_comercial": 244,
            "nome_comercial": "BRUNA FERNANDA CARLOTA ALVES"
             }
],

"dados: [
    {
retorno esse com excedente de linhas possíveis para postar aqui.
    }
]

Comment: O problema é que você está alterando o valor da variável regional no método findPendenciaRegional(event) e você usa essa mesma variável para para iterar no *ngFor="let i of regional". Sacou?

o que você pode fazer é isolar essa variáveis, faz uma chamada que popule essa variavél que você itera no ngFor e usa uma outra no findPendenciaRegional() {}.

Não sei se me fiz claro, pra te ajudar melhor precisamos saber o pq de você alterar o valor do regional no findPendenciaRegional() e tal.

Comment: Entendi. Deu certo. O problema agora é na questão da filtragem mesmo, como relatei ao Leonardo.